# Git clone not loading

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

I just formatted my SSD, and I installed Git, but now git clone is not loading for me when I clone from Bitbucket. It works from Github, so it might be an issue with repository permissions. I don't know how to sign in to Bitbucket, because nothing is popping up telling me to sign in. I tried to clone in VS Code and Git Bash, and it just won't load. I attached screenshots of it cloning. Anyone know what I can do? Do you think I installed Git wrong? It is making the folder that I am trying to clone, but doesn't put the files in it.

Thanks so much!

[image: Git Bash]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you for sure what the problem is but here you have some things that you can try:

Use the `--verbose` option together with the `git clone` command, using **Git Bash** (instead of cloning with VSCode).
**Example:**

> git clone --verbose https://user@bitbucket.org/project/testing.git

That way you can see if it really is stuck or just taking a lot of time.

Also, I recommend using SSH instead of HTTP if possible [you would need to generate an SSH key file on your computer and then add your generated public key (it's called **id_rsa.pub** by default) in Bitbucket. For more information, please read [their documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/).  It's simple and considered safer than HTTPS. Maybe that will also help you in your situation.

If you start using SSH, you can check your connection to Bitbucket by using the following command:

> ssh -vv git@bitbucket.org

For more information about it you can check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1240254) in Super User.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I tried with SSH and it worked, but do you think I should use SSH instead of HTTP all the time? Thanks for the P.S. I guess I forgot to hide it.

Comment: @DotDotCom You are welcome, glad to help ^^ SSH is my go-to every time I can use it so yes, I would say so.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt reinstall git
```

It worked for me.